# Cannot copy code from babel (https://babeljs.io/)

Tags: babeljs

I past in some ES6 code in the left side (https://babeljs.io/), and I get the native javascript on the right side.

I simply want to copy and paste what is generated on the right side. The website does not allow me to select the text to copy.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Use the [REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl) instead.

Comment: thankyou.... add as answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure Babel would accept a pull request to fix this if you/someone submitted one, but you're probably better off using [the REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl) anyway. It allows you to add/remove presets (for example, to make it so you can compile React code) and is generally just a bit more robust.